# keras preprocessing logic

Tags: keras, tensorflow-serving

**Background:**

In a vision application on a GCP, we are using TF serving. The application using TF Serving is written in Go. This application converts the image to Tensor and sends it to the TF serving using gRPC.

**Problem:**

The preprocessing logic in Golang does not work as well as it does in Python, using Keras image library (the accuracy of inference suffers). A part of the reason could be that Python libraries were used during training.

**We tried,**

Tensorflow serving provides a way to introduce a pre-processor that can run on the serving container. It seems to have limited functionality (can't package Keras library with the model). We tried the following two options

**What works** is Keras Preprocessing (Python), on the client side as follows.

```
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(file_name, target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH))
img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
```

… grpc call to TensorflowServing...

Our goal is to use “serving_input_receiver_fn” and preprocess image in the TFServing space as described in this blog post: https://medium.com/devseed/technical-walkthrough-packaging-ml-models-for-inference-with-tf-serving-2a50f73ce6f8

But the following code which is executed as “serving_input_receiver_fn” does not yield the correct inferences.

```
image = tf.image.decode_image(image_str_tensor, channels=CHANNELS                                       dtype=tf.uint8)
image = tf.reshape(image, [HEIGHT, WIDTH, CHANNELS])
```

**Our goal** is to run the following Keras code (in a similar way) inside ““serving_input_receiver_fn” (assuming that we can load the image from “grpc” stream).

```
img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(file_name, target_size=(HEIGHT, WIDTH))
img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
```

Is it possible? This is a massive deployment (70 GPUs & 2300 CPUs) therefore every bit of the performance counts. In our case, the image preprocessing on TF-Serving machine is the most optimal.

Comment: This questions lacks details : what keras preprocessing functions were you using, and how did you try to reproduce them in Go ? Moreover, keras is open source : you can fetch the function code you where using and reimplement them in native TensorFlow to use with the TF Serving preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually have an answer but maybe can point you to some resources to help. I think firstly, keras.preprocessing is supposed to be quite slow, check out https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images and it recommends building pre-processing pipeline as a tf.data.Dataset pipeline

> The above keras.preprocessing method is convienient, but has two
>   downsides:
>
> It's slow. See the performance section below. It lacks fine-grained
>   control. It is not well integrated with the rest of TensorFlow. To
>   load the files as a tf.data.Dataset

Why not include the pre-processing layer as part of the model graph itself so that it will run WITHIN tensorflow serving?